# Каким образом считывать строки с List<String> и подсчитывать количество повторяющихся слов?

Tags: java, list, java-stream

`public String countWords(List<String> lines) {    }`

Это исходные данные. Необходимо реализовать метод.
На входе идет List, где каждый элемент - строка в txt-файле.
Подсчитать количество повторяющихся слов (не менее **n** раз за текст).
Причем, откинуть слова меньшие за мин. размера слова - **min**, и те, что больше за максимальный - **max**.
Все это должно быть реализовано без циклов и условных операторов.
Полагаю,начинать нужно как-то так?

`lines.stream().filter(i -> i.length() >=4)`

Answer (score 0):

Если на входе - строки, то приведенный вами код не будет соответствовать условию, ведь фильтровать надо по словам:

```java
Long wordRepeatCounter = lines.stream()
                .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split(" "))) // делим на слова, 
                // считая что они разделены пробелами (хотя могут встречаться и tab, и неразрывный пробел и...)
                .filter(word -> (word.length() >= minLength) && (word.length() <= maxLength)) // убираем лишние
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toUnmodifiableMap( // собираем в Map
                                s->s, // ключ - само слово
                                s -> 1, // значение - количество повторений
                                Integer::sum)) // которое дополняем в методе "что делать с дубликатами"
                .entrySet().stream()// тут имеем пары "слово":"количество повторений"
                .filter(entry->entry.getValue()>minRepeatCount) // отсекаем те, у кого слишком мало повторений
                .count(); // и на выходе получили количество слов, удовлетворяющее всем условиями.
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно разбить каждую строку на "слова", используя `String.split` -- в простейшем случае при помощи шаблона для разделителей `"\W+"`, или выбирая "слова" при помощи противоположного шаблона `"\w+"`, ипользуя операцию `flatMap` для получения потока слов, к которому уже можно применить необходимые фильтры по длине слова, затем подсчитать частоту слов, применяя `Collectors.counting` / `Collectors.summingInt` и дополнительно отфильтровать слова с нужной частотой:

```java
public long countWords(List<String> lines, int min, int max, int n) {
    return lines
        .stream() // Stream<String> строки
        .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split("\\W+"))) // Stream<String> слова
        .filter(w -> min <= w.length() && w.length() <= max)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            w -> w, // ключ - слово
            Collectors.counting() // значение - частота 
        )) // Map<String, Long>
        .entrySet()
        .stream() //Stream<Map.Entry<String, Long>>
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() >= n)
        .count();
}
```

Второй вариант, использующий метод [`Matcher::results`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--), который возвращает `Stream<MatchResult>`, в свою очередь преобразуемый в поток слов при помощи [`MatchResult::group`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/MatchResult.html#group--):

```java
public long countWords(List<String> lines, int min, int max, int n) {
    Pattern word = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
    return lines
        .stream() // Stream<String> строки
        .flatMap(s -> word.matcher(s).results().map(MatchResult::group)) // Stream<String> слова
        .filter(w -> min <= w.length() && w.length() <= max)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            w -> w, // ключ - слово
            Collectors.summingInt(w -> 1) // значение - частота 
        )) // Map<String, Integer>
        .entrySet()
        .stream() //Stream<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() >= n)
        .count();
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за предоставленное решение!
Но ситуация в том, что не учитывается кириллица. То есть, в потоке проходят в EntrySet() только латинские слова, также только их количество прибавляется в counting().

Comment: Для учета слов из букв кириллицы нужно использовать другие классы: `\P{L}+` - для разделителей (все символы кроме букв), или `\p{L}+` - для слов, содержащих хотя бы одну букву.  Также можно дополнительно привести в один регистр или сравнивать слова без учёта регистра.

Comment: split("[^a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9_]") таким вот образом изменил условие сплита, все заработало как надо.
Ещё раз большое спасибо!